# Error when running github source code from anaconda shell

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda

Following the documentation in [the source code of my interest](https://github.com/machine-reasoning-ufrgs/GNN-GCP) from github, I run `py dataset.py -path adversarial-training --train` from the folder I have cloned repository to.

However, I receive an error

```
  File "C:\Users\~\Git\GNN-GCP\dataset.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

But I have `numpy` installed:

```
conda list
```

yields

```
numpy                     1.19.5                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Where is the problem? Does this mean that the `numpy` must be in the same directory as the cloned repository? Or is there anything else I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add it to the environment variables (path). For example: https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

It is not finding in the environment varaiables